# C++ rmask does not name a type

Tags: c++, sdl

I have the following code from the sdl2 documentation:

```
//Color declartions for later
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
#endif
```

Codeblocks tells me that condition is true, but at compile time, it tells me that rmask doesn't name a type. The error is marked starting in the first line of else statement. Firstly, how do I avoid this? Secondly, do I even need the if statement?

The full error log was:

```
||=== Build: Debug in hayfysh (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp|57|error: ‘rmask’ does not name a type|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp|58|error: ‘gmask’ does not name a type|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp|59|error: ‘bmask’ does not name a type|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp|60|error: ‘amask’ does not name a type|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp||In function ‘int newWindow(int, int, bool, const char*)’:|
/home/andrew/hayfysh/main.cpp|90|error: cannot convert ‘const char*’ to ‘FILE* {aka _IO_FILE*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

already fixed the fifth error by changing fprintf to printf

Comment: Have you made an appropriate typedef for `Uint32`? Otherwise you should use `uint32_t`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just copied a bit of code form [This](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface) and meshed it in with my code

Comment: uint32_t changes nothing

Comment: Are you including the SDL headers? I'm pretty sure that SDL defines `Uint32`. Edit: SDL defines `Uint32` here: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/8da3e4d25202/include/SDL_stdinc.h and `SDL_stdinc.h` is included from `SDL.h`.

Comment: #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

Comment: I probably don't need SDL_image yet, but hey. I will soon

Comment: What happens if you just try `int`? You will need to include `stdint.h` / `cstdint` for `uint32_t`.

Comment: no change to the error

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Please add the complete error message to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98424/discussion-between-andrew-robinson-and-gurka).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this code is exactly where the problem occurs (i.e., it hasn't been extracted from the middle of a function), the problem is that assignment statements aren't allowed at global scope. Change it to initialize the variables (should they be marked const?):

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    Uint32 rmask = 0xff000000;
    Uint32 gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    Uint32 bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    Uint32 amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    Uint32 rmask = 0x000000ff;
    Uint32 gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    Uint32 bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    Uint32 amask = 0xff000000;
#endif
```

Comment: Tank you so much. Now I feel stupid knowing how simple the solution was :/

Comment: FWIW, there seem to be far too many code snippets posted here on SO that create variables then assign to them rather than initializing them. Don't know why that's such a trend...